# "Cannot log after tests are done." for repeated call of render(<App />) in test

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, router

Most of the time I run the following test I get an error message (for some reason not EVERY time) ...

```
describe('<App />', () => {
    it('renders the Component', async () => {   
        await act(async () => render(<MemoryRouter><App /></MemoryRouter>));
    })
    it('renders the Component', async () => {   
        await act(async () => render(<MemoryRouter><App /></MemoryRouter>));
    })
});
```

I need to wrap my component inside `act` because I am using `useEffect` when mounting `App` to fetch user data. For fetching in the test environment I am using the `msw` package to simulate the server responses. Testing the function that calls the user data is successful, so I doubt it has anything to do with this error:

```
Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at App (/Users/.../src/Components/App/App.js:39:65)
        at Router (/Users/.../node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:99:30)
        at MemoryRouter (/Users/.../node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:187:35)".

      37 |                     <NavBar className="NavBar"/>
      38 |                 </header>
    > 39 |                 <Switch>
         |                                                       ^
      40 |                     <Route exact path="/">
      41 |                         <SearchBar onSearch={onSearch} />
      42 |                         <QuoteList quotes={searchResults} />
```

I don't expect anyone to provide me with the solution but any feedback on how to approach this problem/ what to try is welcome because I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what is happening there.

When you render `App` component, as you said, an `useEffect` will fetch some data from APIs. In your case you are using `MSW` to handle HTTP requests. `fetch` data is by the way an async request, so most probably you'll receive data after your first render and at the end of the test.

To resolve your issue you should wait that your fetch is completed and your UI is updated. For example, if your API will return an object that then you'll show to the user you can wait that the DOM has been updated with API response.

If you're using `@testing-library/react` you can use `waitFor`.

I'll suggest you read also the article below that will explain better why you are receiving this warning.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning

Good Luck